# JQuery/Javascript my function is not running when pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, class, rows

I have a button, when I click I want it to get all data from the row. My .php file (i also have php code not included here) looks like so (I trimmed out the table for stackoverflow)

```
<tr class='rowdata'>
     <td>Bob</thd>
</tr>

<input type='submit' class='getRow' value='ClickMe'>

<script>
    $(".getRow").click(function() {
       var rowOfData = $(this).closest(".rowdata");
       alert(rowOfData.text());
    });

</script>
```

Right now I click and nothing happens. Any ideas? The . prefix means it is searching for class.

Comment: This is not how [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) works. You might want to use `.siblings('rowdata')` instead, or `.prev()` / `.prevAll('.rowdata')`, depending. (Also, unrelated: your `<td>` is not correctly closed.)

Comment: @Jeto except an input cannot be a direct sibling of a `tr`

Comment: @Taplar Good point, that is invalid HTML and jQuery won't even find it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Well first, have you checked your developer's console (F12) to see if you have any errors. Are you sure you've referenced the JQuery library.

Next, even with JQuery referenced, `.closest()` is going to search the ancestor elements of the element you call it on. If your button is not a descendant of the element you wish to find, you won't find it.

Now, assuming that `.closest()` does find your row, you are then asking for the `.text()` in the entire row. This may be what you want, but it's seems more likely that you'd want data cell by cell.

Also, your button is a `submit` button which is used for submitting form data, but it doesn't appear that that's what you're doing here. If that's the case, use a regular button.

And, your HTML isn't valid as you have a bad closing tag for your cell.

So, correcting all that:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class='rowdata'>
     <td>Bob</td>
     <td>Smith</td>
     <td><input type='button' class='getRow' value='ClickMe'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
    $(".getRow").click(function() {
       var rowOfData = $(this).closest(".rowdata");
       alert(rowOfData.text()); // Gets all the text in the row
       alert($("td:first-child", rowOfData).text()); // Gets just first cell
    });
</script>
```